# Redux connect function with container component or presentation component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

We are having a discussion at work on what is the best practice for using with the redux connect function. Should we use the presentational component or the container component it's self by putting the presentation component inside the container component. I see some example online where people are putting the presentation component inside a container and some places outside the container It would be great if someone could tell the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer.

I would advise that you should default to defining both your plain component and the connect wrapper in the same file, for simplicity:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {addTodo, toggleTodo} from "./todos";

const mapState = (state) => ({todos: state.todos});

const mapDispatch = {addTodo, toggleTodo};

// Named export for the class
export class TodoList extends React.Component { /* */}

// Default export for the connected component
export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(TodoList);
```

Similarly, I would recommend going with a "feature folder"-type approach for structuring your files.

I have a saved chat log where [I give my thoughts on the whole "container" and "presentational" concept](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ea312b5ee398627ffceb09f89904831f) that you might find useful.  Similarly, note that Dan Abramov [no longer recommends splitting "container" and "presentational" components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Comment: will it create any issue if we separate the component and the container?

Comment: Nope, there's just no reason to separate them most of the time.

Comment: @markerikson thanks for your information. Just one quick question, is TodoList in the example still reusable in other places? I mean if we try to import TodoList from ****, the exported TodoList is the plain presentation component or the container component？How we can re-use TodoList in other places? Thanks

Comment: The component you import matches the import syntax you're using (default imports vs named imports). Here, the connected version is the default export, and the plain version is a named export.  It's up to you to decide if and how it needs to be reused.